Как специализировать std::iterator_traits для класса с двумя шаблонными параметрами?
На этот код
template<typename T, typename E>
class A {
public:
    class iterator;

};

template <typename T, typename E>
struct std::iterator_traits<typename A<T, E>::iterator>
{

};

Компилятор ругается

Class template partial specialization contains template parameters
that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used

Как исправить?

@user7860670, iterator. Испраывил ошибку в заголовке

Тогда избавляйтесь от вложенности. struct std::iterator_traits<AIterator<T, E>>

@user7860670, а почему вложенность неприемлема?

Потому что параметры шаблона родительского класса нельзя вывести. Представьте, что у вас A::iterator является алиасом для int * - как из этого можно вывести T или E.

@user7860670, понял, большое спасибо за ответ

А зачем вообще iterator_traits специализировать? Дефолтная версия будет работать с любым нормально написанным итератором.
